# Add field to DRF's exceptions.PermissionDenied

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Right now django-rest-framework's `exceptions.PermissionDenied` returns a 403 and a detail saying "You don't have permission to perform his action."

```
{"detail": "You don't have permission to perform this action."}
```

I'd like to extend this to include a "reason" field, so I can do something like `MyException(detail="Some detail here", reason="INSUFFICIENT_TIER"). but detail seems to chain quite far up and get transformed in quite a few places. Does anyone know how I might easily add a field that will be returned in the json above?

Here's DRF's exception for reference.

```
class PermissionDenied(APIException):
    status_code = status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
    default_detail = _('You do not have permission to perform this action.')
    default_code = 'permission_denied'
```

It extends APIException:

```
class APIException(Exception):
    """
    Base class for REST framework exceptions.
    Subclasses should provide `.status_code` and `.default_detail` properties.
    """
    status_code = status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    default_detail = _('A server error occurred.')
    default_code = 'error'

    def __init__(self, detail=None, code=None):
        if detail is None:
            detail = self.default_detail
        if code is None:
            code = self.default_code

        self.detail = _get_error_details(detail, code)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.detail)

    def get_codes(self):
        """
        Return only the code part of the error details.

        Eg. {"name": ["required"]}
        """
        return _get_codes(self.detail)

    def get_full_details(self):
        """
        Return both the message & code parts of the error details.

        Eg. {"name": [{"message": "This field is required.", "code": "required"}]}
        """
        return _get_full_details(self.detail)
```

Comment: So, you have a *"custom"* `PermissionDenied`class?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `PermissionClass`. For your case it will look like this:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class MyCustomPermissionClass(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # Basically, any logic you want
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            raise PermissionDenied
```

If you want `MyCustomPermissionClass` to be the default permission class then you need to configure it in your settings: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy
Otherwise, you'll have to specify `permission_classes` in every `ViewSet` or `APIView` you are using like this:

```
class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [MyCustomPermissionClass]
```

More examples you can find here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#examples